# Is there any potential energy that is a function of $\dot{x}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy

The potential energy one always considers in classical mechanics is $V(\mathbf{x})$, of which (Newtonian) gravity, SHM etc. are clear examples.

Are there examples (in classical mechanics or otherwise) where the potential energy depends explicitly on any time derivative $\dot{x}, \ddot{x} \dots$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, consider the Lagrangian for a charged particle in an electromagnetic field:
$$
L = \frac 12 m v^2 - e(\phi - \vec v\cdot A)
$$
where $\vec v$ is the velocity. Also the inertial potential for rotating reference frames:
$$
V(r,\dot r) = - \frac m 2 ({\omega} \times  r)^2 - m\dot  r\cdot (\omega\times r)
$$

**References**

[1]  Moreno. G. A, Barrachina. R. O. A velocity-dependent potential of a rigid body in a rotating frame. *American Journal of Physics* **76**, 1146 (2008)

Comment: Wouldn't that come from a ficticious  force?